# Proof that The diameter of graph $G$ is at most $2$ and $G$ doesn't have a cycle of length $4$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I am new to graph theory and I try to learn how to be better at making proofs and thinking but don't have any idea how to solve the following problem. Could you help me please?

The problem says that there is a network where $2$ users have exactly one common acquaintance. $G = (V,E)$ is the graph used for this network. (for each two users $u,v$ in $V$, $uv$ is in $E$ if $u$ and $v$ doesn't know each other).

I have to come up with a proof to show that the diameter of $G$(named $d(G)$) is at most $2$ and $G$ doesn't have a cycle of length $4$.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to be more accurate in your statement of the problem. Do you mean that  for any (every) pair of "users" (we would normally say vertices, or people, I think), there is exactly one common acquaintance? If there is a cycle of length $4$ what can you deduce? And what is the definition of diameter?

Comment: My question is, why can't you think how you might put the pieces you know together? They are enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Why have you vandalized your question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson This could be a homework or assignment problem. My bad :(

Answer (score 1):

Diameter is the largest distance between any two vertices. Say the diameter of your graph is the distance between vertices $v_1,v_2$. It is given that they have exactly one common neighbour, so $v_1,v_2$ are connected by a path of length $2$ that goes through the common neighbour. This means the distance between $v_1,v_2$ (length of the shortest path joining them) is not more $2$.

For the second part, suppose you have a cycle of length $4$ i.e. $v_1,\color{blue}{e_{12}},v_2,\color{blue}{e_{23}},v_3,\color{blue}{e_{34}},v_4,\color{blue}{e_{41}}$ where all vertices and edges are distinct. Then $v_1,v_3$ have two common neighbours in $v_2,v_4$ which is a contradiction.